# Casting View Controller that implements a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I had a working app with the CBCentralManager  and CBPeripheral components in the same view controller, but now wish to separate the logic so that I can have a separate connection screen. My plan was to create the CBCentralManager on the Connection Page, discover & connect the peripheral, segue to the Dashboard page, and then use the CBPeripheral there.

My code (stripped down) is as follows:

```
var globalBTDevice : CBPeripheral! // Only using this as a global variable because I can't get this to pass using prepareForSegue

class ConnectionPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        globalBTDevice = self.allFoundDevices[indexPath.row]
        centralManager.stopScan()

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("connectedPeripheralSegue", sender: self)
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "connectedPeripheralSegue" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as DashboardViewController! // ERROR here: cannot convert value of type "UIViewController" to type "DashboardViewController!" in coercion.
            globalBTDevice.delegate = destinationVC
        }
        centralManager.connectPeripheral(globalBTDevice, options: nil)
    }
}
```

and

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    // All delegate methods implemented here
}
```

I have a segue set up between the 2 view controllers with Identifier "connectedPeripheralSegue".

Also, the DashboardViewController is actually for a tab of a TabBarController - not sure if this makes a difference.

So the issue I get is that I can't cast the destination view controller as a DashboardViewController on the line marked ERROR. It seems to be caused by the VC implementing the CBPeripheralDelegate Protocol, as if I remove that, then I can cast (however that makes the code useless, as I need this in that class). If I cast to UIViewController instead of DashboardViewController, then setting the delegate on the next line fails with "Cannot assign value of type "UIViewController!" to type "CBPeripheralDelegate?" (which makes sense).

I'm totally out of ideas on how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **as?** operator for optional typecasting. Below code should work,

`let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DashboardViewController`

Comment: Thank you! It compiles now. Unfortunately, the connected peripheral doesn't seem to ever trigger any of the CBPeripheralDelegate methods in the DashboardViewController (even when I've set it as the delegate), so I still have some work to do to see what is wrong.

I'm starting to think that you just have to have CBPeripheralDelegate in the same class as the CBCentralManagerDelegate. If I solve my issues, I'll post back here anyway.